# More effective way to apply a function in one member of a pair in a list but print the other member?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I often find myself working with a list of pairs like {date,number} and I usually have to apply a function to the second members but I want it to print the first one. I tend to use combination of `Position` and `Table`, but I am wondering if there is a more effective and fastest way to do so. For example, I have this list:

```
    BNikkei={{10.0032, 27 Days}, {10.0527, 22 Days}, {10.1283,18 Days}, {10.151,36 Days]}, {10.1655, 62 Days}, {10.3024, 28 Days},... etc}
```

I wanto apply a `Select` for the pairs that are #<16& in the first column and I want to it to either print the whole pair that fills this condition or only the second members (# of days).

Is there a better way than my usual method of finding the position and then using a table to make the pairs? I tried to use a `Map` but I am not sure how to use it with a `Select`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just do `Select[{{10.0032, 27 Days}, {10.0527, 22 Days}, {10.1283, 18 Days}, {10.151, 36 Days}, {10.1655, 62 Days}, {10.3024, 28 Days}}, First[#] < 16 &]`, no?

Comment: You're right, it worked haha, thank you, I've been complicating my life. @J.M.

Comment: J.M.'s suggestion gives you all the pairs that you want. Add [[All,2]] on the end if you want just the second entry of each pair.