# Comparison of tagged units

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, units

Consider this data set:

```
BNikkei = {{10.0032, 27 Days}, {10.0527, 22 Days}, {10.1283, 18 Days}}
```

from a recent question, "[More effective way to apply a function in one member of a pair](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222063/more-effective-way-to-apply-a-function-in-one-member-of-a-pair-in-a-list-but-pri) .."

How to get Select[ to work for #[[2]] < 22 Days?
I tried:

```
Select[BNikkei, #[[2]] < (22 Days) &]
(* {} *)
```

Units in MMA are a great convention. I can't seem to find too much in manuals, on this situation. Unless, I have to derive comparison functions, for my own types???
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html) to represent values with units the comparison will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)" *)
```

As mentioned in the comment by Simon Woods, use [`Quantity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html)

```
BNikkei = {{10.0032, 27 Days}, {10.0527, 22 Days}, {10.1283, 18 Days}} /. 
  x_*Days :> Quantity[x, "Days"];

Select[BNikkei, #[[2]] < Quantity[22, "Days"] &]

(* {{10.1283, Quantity[18, "Days"]}} *)
```

Alternatively, if you are **certain** that all units are "Days"

```
Select[BNikkei, QuantityMagnitude[#[[2]]] < 22 &]

(* {{10.1283, Quantity[18, "Days"]}} *)
```

However, for mixed units

```
BNikkei2 = Append[BNikkei, {10.1, Quantity[3, "Weeks"]}];
```

The first method works with mixed units

```
Select[BNikkei2, #[[2]] < Quantity[22, "Days"] &]

(* {{10.1283, Quantity[18, "Days"]}, {10.1, Quantity[3, "Weeks"]}} *)
```

The second method requires conversion

```
Select[BNikkei2 /. q_Quantity :> UnitConvert[q, "Days"], 
 QuantityMagnitude[#[[2]]] < 22 &]

(* {{10.1283, Quantity[18, "Days"]}, {10.1, Quantity[21, "Days"]}} *)
```

**EDIT:** The built-in conversions are

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, #], "Days"] & /@ {"Weeks", "Months", "Years"}

(* {Quantity[7, "Days"], Quantity[365/12, "Days"], Quantity[365, "Days"]} *)

UnitConvert[Quantity[90, "Days"], #] & /@ {"Weeks", "Months", "Years"}

(* {Quantity[90/7, "Weeks"], Quantity[216/73, "Months"], 
 Quantity[18/73, "Years"]} *)
```

Comment: Any pointers for this scenario. (a) define Days=1, (b) define Weeks=7 days, (c) define Month=30 days. So, I can 3 Months > 90 Days. ** Should I study UnitConvert[ more? ** Manuals seem sparse in this topic?

Comment: ie. Do you have a recommendation for a book or website dealing with UnitConvert[ function?? (Units Overview on WLF MMA, I didn't know about. I'll try it first.]

Answer (score 2):

`Days` is not defined. At least on version 12.1 that I am using, Mathematica does not know what `Days` is.

Hence `<` will fail on it for the same reason that`13 < 4` returns `True`, but `13 < 4 * x` returns `13 < 4 * x` when `x` is undefined.

Now, if you look at

```
expr = 22 Days;
First @ expr
(* 22 *)
Last @ expr
(* Days *)
```

Hence you could also do this

```
  BNikkei = {{10.0032, 27 Days}, {10.0527, 22 Days}, {10.1283, 18 Days}}
  Select[BNikkei, First @ (#[[2]]) < 22 &]

  (* {{10.1283, 18 Days}} *)
```

Another way

```
   Cases[BNikkei, {x_, y_} /; First[y] < 22 :> {x, y}]
  (* {{10.1283, 18 Days}} *)
```